# Issues with arrays, how would i go about solving this?

Tags: arrays

Let's say you have an array of integers. Find all positions p (if they exists) so that the sum of elements from 0 to p is equal to the sum of elements from p + 1 to the end of the array.

Java is preferred for the answer but any other language is fine, thank you.

Comment: Can we assume that all the integers are positive (this is a critical question) ?

Comment: Yes all integers are positive

Comment: Thank you so much, I am new to programming. I like to understand why I am doing something wrong and how I can fix that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can assume that all integers are positive, then it simplifies the problem greatly.  You can walk through the array once to find the sum, and then walk a second time until you (possibly) find a point where the two sums are equal.  The reason this works is that moving either left or right will always increase/decrease the sum.  However, there may be zeroes present, and these also need to be considered.

```
public List<Integer> getPosition(int[] array) {
    List<Integer> result = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    // first walk through the array to determine the total sum
    // cost is O(N)
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i=0; i < array.length; ++i) {
        sum += array[i];
    }

    // next walk through the array again, checking at each step
    // if the running sum be half the total
    // cost is O(N)
    int runningSum = 0;
    int position = -1;
    for (int i=0; i < array.length; ++i) {
        runningSum += array[i];

        // if position found, then break
        if (runningSum == sum / 2) {
            position = i;
            break;
        }
    }

    result.add(position);

    // there may be zeroes to the right of the pivot
    // if so, they are also valid points and must be added
    if (position != -1) {
        int i = position + 1;
        while (array[i] == 0) {
            result.add(i);
            ++i;
        }
    }

    return result;
}

int[] myArray = new int[] {1, 3, 2, 8, 5, 1, 0, 0, 0, 9, 5, 6};
List<Integer> position = getPosition(myArray);
```

**Output:**

```
[5, 6, 7, 8]
```

This answer makes sense because `0 - 5` has a sum of `20` and `6 - 11` also has a sum of `20`.  In addition, we could also start at positions `6`, `7`, or `8` and also divide the array into two sums of 20.

```
[1, 3, 2, 8, 5, 1, 0, 0, 0, 9, 5, 6]
                ^ this value of p divides the array into two sums of 20
                   ^  ^  ^ but any of these values also divide the array
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to solve this problem is to note that the sum of elements from 0 to p must exactly equal the total sum of all elements divided by 2.

This is because both parts (the 0 to p part and the p+1 to the end part) must be equal and the two parts added together make the entire array.

For this solution, you would simply perform two passes.
In the first pass, you sum up all of the elements in the array.

In the second pass, you are looking for every index such that the sum of the array up to that index equals half of the total sum.

In psuedocode:

```
total_amount = sum(array)
current_partial_sum = 0
for i in index of array:
   current_partial_sum += array[i];
   if (current_partial_sum == total_amount/2) {
      add i to the solution
   }
}
```